# Where can I get key metrics of most well known commercial software packages?

Tags: metrics

I'm interested to find some information about codebase size, number of developers, number of commits, duration of development, etc. for commercial software, including: IE, MS Office, Oracle Server, Microsoft IIS, Visual Studio, Windows.

Any ideas where to get this information?

Comment: Best of luck.  Smart companies keep that information very closely held for competitive reasons.

Comment: Even if you could get hold of it, what would it tell you?  Codebase could just be large if the language it was written in is vebose, or suffers from a lot of cut/paste coding.  Similarly, comparing Office to IIS is chalk to cheese so number of developers, etc. will be compeletely different to reflect that (I'd hope)

Comment: This is, IMHO, off-topic at Programmers.  Your question is about software, Programmers.SE is about **programmers.**  You can [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) to bring it more attention.  However, I believe your problem is that the question is in all likelihood impossible to answer, as what you're looking for doesn't exist.  But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

according to this [list of project metrics](http://www.projectcodemeter.com/cost_estimation/help/GL_sloc.htm), Windows XP has 40 million SLOC...